# Where does the stack memory allocated to a thread come from?

Tags: memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

I have few questions regarding java GC and memory management.

In java we define process memory upper bound and lower bound by xmx and xms parameters. Using these parameters JVM allocates young  old and perm space. So if new threads are created then from which memory do stacks memory is allocated to threads? is it from perm space or any other space?

Also static variables of class is allocated to which space young, old or perm space? (I guess perm?)

Does XmX paramenter bounds the young + old gen OR young + old+ perm gen OR young + old + perm + stack  size ??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicly, stack memory comes from stack area, which is independent from heap area and perm
area.

Static variables are allocated in the heap, except string and numeric constants.

`-Xmx` parameter only bounds the young + old parts of the heap, as perm area is not part of it.

Stack area size is set by `-Xss` flag, heap area size is set by `-Xmx` flag and perm area size is set by `-XX:MaxPermSize`.

If you want to dive into JVM internal memory management I recommend this [blog entry](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/01/the-java-memory-architecture-1-act/).

Answer (score 0):

The thread stack space is controlled by another option *-Xss*. [Here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5258715) is a reference that might help you which is on this particular topic.

Comment: I know about -Xss flag. my question is : from where does memory allocated to thread using -Xss option come? or you can answer this question : Does XmX paramenter bounds the young + old gen OR young + old+ perm gen OR young + old + perm + stack size ?? If it does not include stack size then from where stack space is allocated?

Answer (score 0):

on solaris you can use 'ulimit -a' to see the stack limit of processes. I think that the threads stack is taken from this resource. I am wondering if the JVM will issue garbage collection when there is enough space in the heap for the threads, but not enough space for their stack.